# TypeError occurs upon inserting a working function into a setTimeout call

Tags: javascript, node.js, callback

A snipit of code that I am using works perfectly when it contains the first line of code shown below.  However, when I replace that line with the second line of code shown below, a "TypeError [ERR_INVALID_CALLBACK]: Callback must be a function" error is thrown.  Any suggestions on what I might do to fix this problem?  Thanks.

```
getData(body);
setTimeout(getData(body), 0);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

JavaScript `setTimeout(function[, delay, arg1, arg2, ...])` takes the name of the function you want to execute as its first argument. **Emphasis on the name of the function**. This means `getData` in your case instead of `getData()` or `getData(body)`. The second argument is the time to wait for before the function executes. The next argument (or comma-separated list of arguments) are the argument you want to supply to your function in the order your function expect them. This means written correctly, your code should look like this: `setTimeout(getData, 0, body)`.

Seeing that your `setTimout` function is not delayed at all by setting delay to 0, you could just call `getData(body)` normally and it will do its work. Just saying.

Comment: Great answer and (after taking into account the adjustment in syntax relating to how the body argument is handled) , it worked for curing my error problem in my 2nd line of code.  However, instead of returning the data that the 1st line does, I now get an "undefined" complaint.  The fact that undefined is returned suggests that the retrieval of the data has not yet been completed.  That's why I'm not just using "getData(body)" as you suggest.  I am rather wrapping that inside setTimeout 0 in order to delay the execution of getData until the stack clears, i.e., the data is retrieved.  Ideas?

Comment: BTW, my environment is node.js.  FWIW.

Comment: I will need to see the definition of your getData() function to help any further.